# Mosfet switch implementation

Tags: mosfet, boolean-algebra

[image: mosfet switch]

[image: problem 6_1]

This is the second part of the problem which I try to solve from textbook.
I wrote the truth table. Z is 1 only if A, B and C are 0.

I've found a boolean equation like that :

\$ \large Z = \bar {A} \bar {B} \bar {C} \$

But according to the solution manual the answer is :

\$ \large Z = \bar {A} {B} {C} \$

Which one is correct?

Citation :

> Agarwal, Anant, Lang, Jeffrey. Foundations of Analog and Digital
>   Electronic Circuits

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're correct and the solution manual is wrong, but I don't have time to double-check right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer as I (and you) have calculated is 
$$
Z = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}
$$

The truth table is -

```
    A B C | Z
    - - - - -
    0 0 0 | 1
    0 0 1 | 0
    0 1 0 | 0
    0 1 1 | 0
    1 0 0 | 0
    1 0 1 | 0
    1 1 0 | 0
    1 1 1 | 0
```

Even if we think that the solution-maker has somehow forgot the 'manufacturing error' the answer comes out to be 
$$
Z = \bar{A}\bar{B}
$$
and the truth table is -

```
A B C | Z
- - - - -
0 0 0 | 1
0 0 1 | 1
0 1 0 | 0
0 1 1 | 0
1 0 0 | 0
1 0 1 | 0
1 1 0 | 0
1 1 1 | 0
```

Comment: In fact at the first part of the question they ask the output of the circuit without 'manufacturing error' . And the solution is \$ \large Z = \overline {A+B} \$ which is equal to \$ \large Z = \bar{A}\bar{B} \$ from De Morgan's laws. At page 263 of textbook.